# Displaying articles from a wordpress site on a non-wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, parsing, rss

What is the easiest way to display articles entries posted on a wordpress site (from a particular category) onto another non-wordpress site that is built in PHP/MySQL.

I understand wordpress uses MySQL so in theory I could connect via PHP to the database and pull the content directly if I can figure out the schema used

I know I can get an RSS feed - is there a parser available that I could use to get all article content including images etc?

Answer (score 4):

### Wordpress content on non-Wordpress pages in *same* domain

This is a very database-intensive method as it loads almost the entirety of Wordpress behind the scenes, but it's easy and well-documented:

**[Display Wordpress content outside of your blog](http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages)**

This assumes that the Wordpress blog is on the same server as the non-Wordpress content and you can reference wp-load.php

---

### Wordpress content on non-Wordpress pages on *remote* domain

One of the simplest simplest methods to syndicate content onto a remote domain is to parse the RSS feed using [MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/).

There are a large number of code samples available:

- http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/links.shtml
- http://www.technologytricks.com/rss-read-php-magpierss/
- http://www.oneandoneis2.org/MagpieHowTo.php

To get the RSS feed for a particular category, use something like

> http://www.example.com/?cat=42&feed=rss2
>
> http://example.com/category/categoryname/feed

More here:

- [Wordpress Feeds | WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Categories_and_Tags)

Comment: 'Outside of your blog' but is that outside of your site? It looks like in that example, it's still on the same server whereas I'm talking about a different server as well, which doesn't have wordpress.

Comment: Updated my answer to cover the remote domain solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the other pages are located on the same server you can do this by loading the wp-load.php file

First add this to the top of the page to load wp-load.php

```
<?php
// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wordpress/wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=1');
?>
```

Then you can loop all the content via:

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more...</a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Checkout this link: [The Loop (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: You can change you account name without creating a new user.