# Access wordpress from a directory that its not installed in

Tags: wordpress, directory

I have a directory `/examples/` that is at the root of my site. I want to retain this hierarchy:

```
/examples/foo1/
/examples/foo2/ ...etc
```

I also have wordpress installed at the root with my posts shown on the home page. I found out the long way that I cant access any wordpress functions or anything wordpress related from within the `/examples/` directory or any folders within examples directory.

I know I can make a page within wordpress called examples and make sub pages under examples to get the desired directory, but I dont want to end up with 300 subpages of example content. Thats like treating the page section as a post section.

Is there a way I can access wordpress variables and functions from the `/examples/` directory that I made? Or is there another method that I have not thought of to get this directory and still have access to wordpress stuff?

I hope this is clear.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to a question previously answered. Refer to the instructions for displaying WP content in the *same* domain:

- **[Displaying articles from a wordpress site on a non-wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387336/displaying-articles-from-a-wordpress-site-on-a-non-wordpress-site/5393444#5393444)**

Comment: <?php
// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wordpress/wp-load.php');
?>

Comment: So that looks like that is all i need, thanks :D i just need to change the directory.

Comment: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')

Comment: Im getting that error. My wp-load.php is at the root. so this should be right: <?php
// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/wp-load.php');
?>

Comment: PHP gets the paths from the root of the filesystem on which is running, it doesn't use your html docroot, so '/wp_load.php' is pointing to a file at the root of the filesystem. Use relative paths instead if you don't know the absolute ones, like: '../wpfolder/wp-load.php'. The absolute path is probably something like: '/var/www/users/domain.com/wpfolder/wp-load.php'.

Comment: echo getcwd(); i used that to see the directories. Then i just used this to go up a few directories require( '../../wp-load.php');